# SQL how to not show a row with same name that has a higher value in one column

Tags: sql, sql-server

So I am running a query that returns `Name` of type `varchar(100)` and `revision` as `int` and `status` of type `varchar(25)`.

Due to how the table and database are, it saves multiple of the same `Name` but it has different `revision` numbers.

What I need to learn is how to only show a row with the highest `revision` if the project is the same AND if the highest revision has a `status` of Closed, do not include that name at all.

I know I can use `WHERE Status NOT LIKE 'Closed'` but I need to figure out how to just get the highest revision first so I can use that line.

This is the table I have now:

```
|name  | revision| Status  |
+------+---------+---------+
|Proj1 | 3       | Closed  |
|Proj1 | 2       | Active  |
|Proj1 | 1       | Proposed|
|Test2 | 2       | Active  |
|Test2 | 1       | Proposed|
|Proj2 | 2       | Active  |
|Proj2 | 1       | Proposed|
```

What I want it to look like

```
|name  | revision|Status  |
+------+---------+--------+
|Test2 | 2       |Active  |
|Proj2 | 2       |Active  |
```

What I have so far:

```
SELECT 
    System_rev,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY system_title ORDER BY System_Rev DESC) system_title,
    TP.ProjectNodeName AS Project_Name,                
    System_state
FROM 
    Tfs_Warehouse.dbo.DimTeamProject TP
INNER JOIN 
    Tfs_Warehouse.dbo.DimWorkItem wi ON TP.ProjectNodeSK = wi.TeamProjectSK
WHERE 
    wi.CDS_Project_HotFixRelated LIKE '1'
    AND system_title = 1
    AND wi.System_IsDeleted  = '0'
    AND wi.System_WorkItemType LIKE 'Request'
    -- AND CONVERT(VARCHAR, wi.System_CreatedDate , 121) <= DATEADD(month, -1, GETDATE())
GROUP BY
    System_Title, System_Rev
```

As of now I get an error

> Column 'Tfs_Warehouse.dbo.DimTeamProject.ProjectNodeName' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

Comment: (1) You would better show your current query (or a simplified, representative example of it), so one can optimize this from the start. (2) Please tag your question with the database you are running: mysql, oracle, sqlserver...?

Comment: Which version of MySQL? Does it support ROW_NUMBER?

Comment: *dbo* and the error message seem to indicate SQL Server instead of MySQL. Why do you GROUP BY if you don't have any aggregates?

Comment: @dnoeth, when I remove group by I, get Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'Initial Release' to data type int.

Comment: what does `select version();` show?

Comment: @ysth Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM) 
My mistake it was using this

Answer (score 3):

```
with cte as
 ( select t.*,
     -- highest revision gets "1"
     row_number() 
     over (partition by name
           order by revision desc) as rn
   from tab as t
 )
select * from cte
where rn = 1             -- highest revison
  and status <> 'closed' -- if not closed
```

Edit based on your query:

```
with cte as
 (
    SELECT 
       System_rev,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by system_title order by System_Rev desc) as rn,
       TP.ProjectNodeName    AS Project_Name,                
       System_state
                 
    FROM Tfs_Warehouse.dbo.DimTeamProject TP
    INNER JOIN Tfs_Warehouse.dbo.DimWorkItem wi
            ON TP.ProjectNodeSK = wi.TeamProjectSK

      -- if CDS_Project_HotFixRelated is a string this should be = '1'
      -- and if it's a numeric column                            = 1
    WHERE wi.CDS_Project_HotFixRelated LIKE '1' 
      AND wi.System_IsDeleted  = '0' -- numeric or string?
      AND wi.System_WorkItemType  = 'Request'
      -- what data type is System_CreatedDate?
      --AND CONVERT(VARCHAR, wi.System_CreatedDate , 121) <= DATEADD(month, -1,GETDATE())

       -- no group by 
       -- Group by System_Title, System_Rev
 )
select * 
from cte
where rn = 1                   -- highest revison
  and System_state <> 'closed' -- if not closed
```

Comment: What I have so far will be in OP

Answer (score 1):

use row_number() if your dbms support that

```
select a.* from (select *,row_number()(over partition by name order by revision desc) rn
 from table_name t1
Where name not in( select name where  Status = 'Closed')
) a where a.rn=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use groupBy:

```
SELECT name, MAX(revision) revision, status FROM projects
WHERE status <> 'closed'
GROUP BY name, status
```